# Java compile time error in case of casting

Tags: java

The below code gives me compile time error **Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte**

```
int i = 10;
byte b = i;
```

but the below doesn't

```
 final int i = 10;
 byte b = i;
```

I don't understand why compiler is behaving in case of final?

Comment: Are you sure? It is not giving any error for me. Post the error message.

Comment: 1st code snippet gives compile time error.. Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte but 2nd doesn't

Comment: If you try with `final int i = 128;` it won't work since it will not fit into the byte anymore.

Comment: @anand: I thought you were complaining about second snippet. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's because 10 fits in a byte, but if the integer was something that takes more than 8 bits then it wouldn't be able to properly do this assignment anymore.

**Edit**

To clarify, making it final is allowing the compiler to treat the int as a constant so it can do constant folding. It's probably preventing the assignment with the non-final int because it doesn't know that value at compile time and it could be way bigger than what a byte can hold.

Comment: Well the `final` would indicate to the compiler that `i` is declared to be 10 and should always be 10, and will not at some point end up something too big for a byte.

Comment: ignore my comment. I completely mis-understood the question.

Answer (score 3):

Case 1: compile error because an `int` might not fit into a `byte`; an explicit cast is necessary
Case 2: the compiler compiles the 2nd statement to `byte b = 10;` (as `i` is `final`), so no error

Comment: I didn't get why compiler compiles the 2nd statement to byte b =10

Comment: because you declared it as "final" that means no where in the code will the value ever change, so compilers can do some optimization and just treat that as a constant value. Since the value is known at compile time not to be bigger than a byte, it lets you do the assignment.

Comment: i is final, meaning its value never changes. So an obvious optimization that the compiler does is inline its value to every reference to it, e.g. byte b = 10. If you change the value of i to, say 128 (i.e. just 1 value beyond the bound of a byte), then you should also see a compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int i=45;
final int j=i;
byte b=j;
```

Compare this with

```
final int j=56;
byte b=j;
```

this ll give you an idea how implicit narrowing of int to byte takes place i.e. it only takes place if the value assigned is a constant expression

Answer (score 0):

> I didn't get why compiler compiles the 2nd statement to byte b =10 – anand

Thats because, you are instructing the compiler that the variable 'i' will hold '10' as the value always. Hence, the compiler would replace 'i' with '10' wherever it is referenced. By doing so, it would make the job of JVM easier!

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 :

```
int i = 10;
byte b = i;
```

`int` primitive type value can range from  `-2,147,483,648 [-231]` aka `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `+2,147,483,647 [2 31-1]` aka `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

`int i= 10`  means compiler assumes the value of int can be rage from  -2,147,483,648 [-231] to +2,147,483,647 [2 31-1],  but byte cannot hold this value. Thus compiler gives the error.

Case 2 :

```
final int i = 10;
byte b = i;
```

Here int variable declared as final and initialized to 10. byte can hold values between  -128 to 127 and it will not be changed through out program. because of this reason compiler not gives any error.

If you declare the same variable with 128 it gives error.
Ex:

```
final int i = 128;
byte b = i;
```