# Type cast vs literal assignment

Tags: java, casting

Consider the following:

```
class TypeCast {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte by = 4;   // Compiler casts int literal to byte
        int in = 4;
        byte byt = in; // Compilation Error: compiler can not cast automatically. WHY?
    }
}
```

I know compiler can do the narrowing in case of literal assignment. But it can't do the same when assignment involves variable instead of literal. Why?

EDIT: I think most people could not understand what I was trying to ask. It is not about assigning 'out-of-range' value it is about assigning 'in-range' value to `byte` and let compiler take care of the narrowing. It is quite obvious 'byte' won't be able to handle out of range value and explicit conversion would require(and that is not I want to know).

Given value falls in `byte` range, what is the difference between `int` literal assignment to `byte` and `int` type variable assignment to `byte` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java compile time error in case of casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203019/java-compile-time-error-in-case-of-casting)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203019/java-compile-time-error-in-case-of-casting

Comment: try doing by = 1000 and you will get the same error. literals/non-literal has nothing to do with it

Comment: Understand that allowing an integer literal (which is nominally defined to be 32 bits) to be assigned to a narrower data type, *when the literal can be seen by the compiler to be as "narrow" as the target data type*, is merely a convenience, both for the programmer and the compiler (since the compiler doesn't have to provide literal decimal forms for `short`, `byte`, and `char`).

Comment: *"Why?"* There's no magic reason. Some languages always allow implicit narrowing conversion (C++ for example). Java doesn't. *"It is not about assigning 'out-of-range' value"* Yes, it is, because this is why it's not allowed. If you think your question is different, then we can't tell what you're asking. (For example are you trying to ask why the compiler can't tell that `in` is 4...?)

Comment: @Radiodef I wasn't asking why compiler can't tell `in` is 4. But I would like to know it now.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Because in your code you can change the value of a variable. That's why it is not allowed to assign an int variable to a byte, but if you declare your int variable as final it will allow try this:

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       final int i = 10;
       byte by = i;
    }
 }
```

It means 10 is in range of byte, so all is fine, but if you write

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final int i = 10000;
      byte by = i;
   }
 }
```

it will give you an error, because 10000 is not in the range of a byte.

Answer (score 7):

The main reason, IMHO, is that a code like that (which actually doesn't compile)

```
  int in = ...   // what if in == 1234?;
  byte byt = in; // then byt == -46. Can you expect this?
```

is *dangerous*, because of potential *overflow* (int `1234` becomes `-46` byte). However,

```
  byte byt = 4;
```

is *safe* since illegal (overflow) code like

```
  byte byt = 1234; // doesn't compile
```

will cause a *compile time error*. You can *insist*, however:

```
  // I'm warned about the overflow, but do as I command...
  byte byt = (byte) 1234; // -46
```

or

```
  int in = ...
  byte byt = (byte) in; // I know what I'm doing! Cast it, please
```

Answer (score 2):

Because assigning an `int` to a `byte` in general doesn't make sense; the compiler *should* fail on that kind of statement.

The reason the compiler accepts assigning a literal integral value to a byte variable is that it can (and does) validate that assignment at compile-time, so it's completely safe, and does not really require any kind of "cast" at all. If the assignment is invalid, the compiler will fail:

```
bash$ qjava 'byte b = 128;'
...\QJava.java:4: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
    byte b = 128;
             ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

byte by = 4 is a special case. There is no "cast" involved as such as only integer values that happen to be within byte range -128 to 127 are allowed...

Try and use a value outside this range and you'll get the same error

```
byte small = -128;    // <== OK
byte big = 127;       // <== OK
byte tooSmall = -129; // <== error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte
byte tooBig = 128;    // <== error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte
```

Answer (score 1):

Your byte can only represent -128 <= X <= 127.

A byte is 8 bits. Where the first bit is the sign, 0 (positive) or 1 (negative).

For positive, the other seven bits represent the binary number.

The zero is 00000000. 127 is 01111111.

For negatives, it uses a system called [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

With two's complement 10000000 represent -128 and no another zero.

Answer (score 0):

If C# had included a byte literal type, and defined the Boolean operators (Byte | Byte), (Byte ^ Byte), (Byte & Int64), (Int64 & Byte), (Byte & UInt64), and (UInt64 & Byte) to yield byte results when given the indicated operands, then the language could reasonably require that code which wants to store something into a `Byte` should use an expression of type `Byte`.  The creators of the language, however, presumably felt that the benefits of adding real support for types shorter than `Int32` were insufficient to justify the cost, and thus it has very few kinds of expressions that yield anything smaller than `Int32`.

To allow for the fact that assignment of literal values to short variables is *extremely* common, because C# has no other sensible way of handling such things, the language allows integer constants in the range 0 to 255 to be implicitly converted to `Byte`.  There's nothing in the type system design that would imply this behavior--it's basically a kludge to handle the most common situations where the lack of proper byte-type support would otherwise pose a major annoyance.